# Why is there so much focus on highly symmetric configurations in electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, soft-question, education, approximations

I was told that in real life, there isn't always high symmetry in what one wants to work with. So why do we spend so much time dealing with highly symmetric problems that have elegant, straightforward solutions when this is usually not possible in practice? Shouldn't we get used to dealing with more realistic, complex problems? Perhaps it has made the usefulness of something like Gauss's law conflated due to its main usefulness with highly symmetric and highly intuitive configurations.

Answer (score 3):

Even though many situations in real life don't have nice symmetries, they can usually be *approximated* to some degree by situations that do. Even in situations where the accuracy of the symmetric approximation isn't enough, the exactly-solvable symmetric situations can help you gain *intuition* about how such a system should qualitatively behave, which is very important from an educational standpoint.